# Message queue not receiving information as expected

Tags: c, message-queue

I'm coding a program and I wanted to use a message queue in order to schedule the program ending. This is a schema of the code:

```
typedef struct {
    long id;
    int num;
}Message;

int disconnect = 0;

void disconnection() {
    disconnect = 1;
}

int main () {
   
    //...

    int n = fork();
    int id_queue = msgget(ftok("connection.h", 66), 0600|IPC_CREAT);

    switch(n) {

        case 0: //child process

            Message message;
            message.id = 1;
            message.num = 0;

            while (1) {
                // ...

                msgrcv(id_queue, (struct msgbuf *) &message, sizeof(int), 1, IPC_NOWAIT);

                if (message.num == 1) break;
            }

            write(1, "Exit successfull\n", strlen("exit successfulll")); //The child process does not reach this line

            msgctl(id_queue, IPC_RMID, (struct msqid_ds *)NULL);
        break;

        default: //main process
            signal(SIGINT, disconnection);

            while (!disconnect) { /* ... */ }

            Message msg;
            msg.id = 1;
            msg.num = 1;

            msgsnd(id_queue, (struct msgbuf *) &msg, sizeof(int), IPC_NOWAIT);

            wait(NULL); //waiting for child process to end
        break;

}
```

As you can see, the program works until I interrupt it with a `SIGINT`. The disconnection process in order to end the child process is to send a message that is just an `int` and if it's `1`, child process loop should break. I have tested it and it doesn't enter (doesn't print the `write` after the `while(1)` loop) so I'm figuring out I have some errors sending or receiving the data through the message queue.

What's wrong?

Also, the program ends after I send `SIGINT` interruption and `wait(NULL)` is not waiting for child process to end, as the `write` doesn't print through the screen...

Comment: Tip: If you need to use a global variable inside an handler you should declare it as `static volatile sig_atomic_t`, otherwise safe access is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of issues.

When you do `ctrl-c`, the signal will be sent *both* parent and the child. The *child* must *disable* the signal or it will be killed by the default signal action.

The parent should *not* use `IPC_NOWAIT` when doing the `msgsnd`.

In the child, it *can* do `IPC_NOWAIT`, but we have to check the return value and *loop* if it returns -1 (i.e. the message contents is *not* valid otherwise).

You can *not* put a scoped declaration inside a `case` [IIRC]. Better to move these to function scope.

`disconnect` should be declared `volatile`. This is sufficient for your use case. In the more general case [as others have mentioned], you should use `stdatomic.h` primitives.

There's a lot of hardcoding of special constants (e.g. `1` for `.num`).

The length arguments to `msgsnd` and `msgrcv` are hardwired with `sizeof(int)`. This won't scale too well [if other fields are added to the `Message` struct].

You *can* use `ftok` to get a `key_t` value. But, here, it's overkill. Just use `IPC_PRIVATE` in the parent [before the `fork`]. That's what most programs do if they're *only* doing `fork`

---

I've refactored the code. I've marked changes using `cpp` conditionals:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif
```

Anyway, here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define fault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0)

typedef struct {
    long id;
    int num;
} Message;

// equates to id
enum {
    MSGID_ANY,                      // receive any message
    MSGID_TOCLD,                    // send/receive messages to child
    MSGID_TOPAR,                    // send/receive messages to parent
};

// equates to num
enum {
    NUM_DO_X,                       // perform "x" ...
    NUM_DO_Y,                       // perform "y" ...
    NUM_STOP,                       // stop request
};

#if 0
int disconnect = 0;
#else
volatile int disconnect = 0;
#endif

void
disconnection()
{
    disconnect = 1;
}

int
main()
{
#if 1
    Message msg;
    int err;
#endif

    // ...

#if 0
    int n = fork();
    int id_queue = msgget(ftok("connection.h", 66), 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
#else
    int id_queue = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
    printf("parent: id_queue=%d\n",id_queue);
    int n = fork();
#endif

    switch (n) {
    case 0:  // child process
#if 0
        Message message;
#endif
        msg.id = MSGID_TOCLD;
        msg.num = 0;

#if 1
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
#endif

        while (1) {
            // ...
#if 0
            msgrcv(id_queue, (struct msgbuf *) &msg, sizeof(int), 1,
                IPC_NOWAIT);
#else
            err = msgrcv(id_queue, (struct msgbuf *) &msg,
                sizeof(msg) - sizeof(msg.id), MSGID_TOCLD, IPC_NOWAIT);
            if (err < 0)
                continue;
            printf("child: got num=%d\n",msg.num);
#endif
            if (msg.num == NUM_STOP)
                break;
        }

        // The child process does not reach this line
#if 0
        write(1, "Exit successfull\n", strlen("exit successfulll"));
#else
        printf("Exit successful\n");
#endif

        msgctl(id_queue, IPC_RMID, (struct msqid_ds *) NULL);
        break;

    default:  // main process
        signal(SIGINT, disconnection);

        while (!disconnect) {
        }
        printf("Parent got signal\n");

#if 0
        Message msg;
#endif
        msg.id = MSGID_TOCLD;
        msg.num = NUM_STOP;

#if 0
        msgsnd(id_queue, (struct msgbuf *) &msg, sizeof(int), IPC_NOWAIT);
#else
        err = msgsnd(id_queue, (struct msgbuf *) &msg,
            sizeof(msg) - sizeof(msg.id), 0);
        if (err < 0)
            fault("parent: msgsnd fail -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
#endif

        // waiting for child process to end
        wait(NULL);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, parent used `IPC_NOWAIT` because otherwise the program would get blocked waiting for the child process to receive the message, but before the `msgrcv` in the child process there's a `sem_wait` in the original code so I used `IPC_NOWAIT` in the parent so right after I send a `sem_signal` to that semaphore without blocking the code forever. Is this a good reasoning to keep using `IPC_NOWAIT` or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm guessing [based on the `sem_wait`], but it seems like you want to have a way to manage shared buffers as a work queue between processes/threads. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996848/canonical-way-to-broadcast-data-to-multiple-processes-in-linux/35998742#35998742 It has a bunch of detail on this. With `msg*`, you may not _need_ to use `sem*`. It's a good design to have a process/thread only wait on _one_ thing. After reading the link, let me know if it helps.